# Lock iOS app to prevent all IBActions and scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to implement the following function in my iOS app.When an on-screen lock button is pressed:

- the app becomes locked and all buttons become inactive except the
  unlock button
- the app is no longer scrollable

Please help, I have no idea how to get started!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code and Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please make an attempt and ask for help here if you get stuck, or ask for help on the Apple Developer Forums.

Answer (score 0):

Give your unlock button a custom tag. Let's say: 99. Loop through each UIView in your self.view.subviews and check if it's an UIButton. Then check if it's not the unlock button (if the tag is different than 99). If it's not, disable user interaction on it.

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        if(subview.tag != 99){
            [subview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        }else{
            //subview is the unlock button
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have property with boolean variable that is on or off depending on wether its locked or not, and in the code, before the button does anything, you check

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouch:(id)sender
{
if (Bool == YES) {
    //do normal things
}
else
    //no code
}
```

or you could have a second view controller. and when the lock button is pressed, it goes to that view controller